# SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects: Loop through set list of tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to use SSIS (sql server integration services) Transfer SQL Server Objects, to loop through a pre-made list of Table names and then execute the Task on just that one Table? (with variable name, or whatever)?

I see the place where you can pre-select a bunch of tables to Copy, but for the bigger picture of the overall automated process, logging, and logging information about backup events back into another table..... I'd prefer to execute the Task once on each table - but how can I tell the task to do just that one table?

Do I have to change it via script task at run time?  Why doesn't it just have an expression that can be set to a variable and  "single table" option?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

You can use a `For-each Loop` with a `'Foreach ADO Enumerator'`. You need to first save the sql query result to a `'Rowset destination'` with an `execute sql task`. Following that, use the `Foreach task`. you may need to add some `variables` too, to realize the condition checking.

Comment: I know I can do that, if I manually generate all of the create table sql first, for each table.  That would be extremely time consuming and would be wrong any time the table design changed.  I was looking for specifically changing the collection of tables.